# Python: filename contains String (metachar?)

Tags: python, contains, metacharacters

I'm using os.walk(directory) to show recursively all the files from that directory.
The thing is that i need to show only the files that contain an asked String in its name, and it has to manage metachars too.

What i have now is:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir1):
        for filename in files:
            if substring in filename:
                name_path = os.path.join(root,filename)
                list.insert(END, name_path)
```

This works nicely, but if  `substring = *`, as i dont have files containing an ' * ', my list is empty.

So, how do I get this to work if `substring` contains a METACHAR?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are looking for fnmatch:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch

Comment: LOL.
now I get this working ONLY if I introduce a metachar. If substring is something like "exercise1" it doesnt find it

Comment: Found it. substring must be substring=" * "+substring+" * "

Answer (score 4):

You can use glob. 
It's very handy and similar to find command in Linux.

```
import glob
glob.glob("/home/user/*.txt")
```

Search in multiple subdirectories

```
glob.glob("/home/user/*/*.txt")
```

or

```
glob.glob("/home/user/logs?.txt")
```